# Highest total salary

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables with the following values and the question is : Find the name of the instructor with the highest total salary along with the names of the dancers he trains.

[image: TABLES]

I was thinking something like :

```
 Select Instructor.name, Dancer.name 
 FROM  Instructor, Dancer, Info 
 WHERE Instructor.i_ID=Info.ints_id 
       AND Dancer.d_ID=Info.danc_id 
 GROUP BY Info.inst_id, Info.danc_id 
 ORDER BY SUM(Info.salary) 
 DESC LIMIT  2;
```

But the output is not right and also I am not suppose to know how many dancers every instructor has, so DESC LIMIT 2 is definitely wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Join properly the tables and group by instructor to get the total salary for each.
Then sort descending by the total salary and keep only the 1st row.
With `group_concat()` you get the names of the dancers as a comma separated list:

```
select i.name, 
       sum(n.salary) total_salary,
       group_concat(d.name) dancers
from instructor i
inner join info n on n.inst_id = i.i_id
inner join dancer d on d.danc_id = d.d_id
group by i.i_id, i.name
order by total_salary desc limit 1
```

Note that this query will return only 1 row, so if there are 2 instructors with the same top total salary you will get only 1.

If you want in the results ties in the top salary then use a `HAVING` clause:

```
select i.name, 
       sum(n.salary) total_salary,
       group_concat(d.name) dancers
from instructor i
inner join info n on n.inst_id = i.i_id
inner join dancer d on d.danc_id = d.d_id
group by i.i_id, i.name
having total_salary = (select sum(salary) from info group by inst_id order by sum(salary) desc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
select tab3.name "Instructor",tab2.name "Dancer"
from info tab1 
inner join 
dancer tab2 on tab1.dance_id=tab2.d_id
inner join 
(select t1.inst_id,t2.name, sum(t1.salary) as  "total_salary" from info t1 
inner join instructor t2 
on t1.inst_id=t2.i_id 
group by t1.inst_id,t2.name
order by total_salary desc limit 1) tab3

on tab3.inst_id=tab1.inst_id
```

[DB-FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXkixKNCkL4JQtptMEexyy/1)

Answer (score -1):

well it's a bit odd relation table but you could try something like this

```
SELECT 
    ins.name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(inf.salary ORDER BY inf.salary DESC),',',1) salary,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(d.name ORDER BY inf.salary DESC),',',1) dancer_name 
FROM Instructor ins
JOIN Info inf ON (ins.i_ID=inf.inst_id)
JOIN Dancer d on (d.d_ID=danc_id)
GROUP BY ins.i_ID 
LIMIT 1;
```